# lines not appearing in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe `data`. I'm trying to create a lineplot using `ggplot`, where I have 2 lines (the two dates under `Date`), `Key` as my x-axis, `Value` as my Y axis.

```
structure(list(Date = c("2020-11-01", "2020-11-28", "2020-11-01", 
"2020-11-28", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-28", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-28", 
"2020-11-01", "2020-11-28", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-28", "2020-11-01", 
"2020-11-28"), Key = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("3M", "2YR", "5YR", "10YR", 
"20YR", "25YR", "30YR"), class = "factor"), Value = c(3.6, 4.25, 
4.22, 4.37, 7.09, 7.065, 9.315, 8.96, 11.65, 11.05, 11.77, 11.145, 
11.73, 11.075)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

here is the code I'm using for my plot. However, its not coming out as desired (the curves aren't appearing on the plot, added an image below)

```
ggplot(dat2, aes(x = Key, y = Value, col = Date)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

This is how I would want it to appear like

[image]

Comment: There's a clue in the message: "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?" Add `, group = Date` after `col = Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to convert the 'Key' to `numeric`, plot and then change the x axis

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat2 %>%
    mutate(Keyn = as.numeric(factor(Key))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Keyn, y = Value, col = Date)) + 
        geom_line() + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(as.numeric(factor(dat2$Key))), 
       labels = unique(dat2$Key))
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set the [group aesthetic](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html).  By default, ggplot2 will set the group aesthetic to the interaction of all discrete variables.  In your case, this results in each row being its own group, meaning no lines are actually drawn.  Setting the group aesthetic results in the correct graphic being produced:

```
ggplot(dat2, aes(x = Key, y = Value, col = Date, group=Date)) +
  geom_line()
```